# How to use the closure template API with the template in string form instead of the File form

Tags: google-closure-templates

The closure template API `SoyFileSet.Builder` has several ways to define templates that one wants to use. The one I know how to use is the following:

```
 SoyFileSet sfs = builder.add(new File("...")).build();
```

There is a second way to create the `SoyFileSet` with a template in string form:

```
add(CharSequence content, String filePath)
```

This `add` method takes a `CharSequence` which I presume is the template in string form (the documentation states "Adds an input Soy file, given the file content provided as a string, as well as the desired file path for messages.") I can not figure out what the second parameter is about. I don't need it at the moment. Setting it to null or "" throws an exception. Can anyone share an example on how to properly use the second API?

Answer (score 0):

an example from a groovy script I have

soyFileSetBuilder.add(getFileContent("src/main/resources/soy/$it"), it)

where "it" is the file name. now the reason this is so, is so you can get error messages from the soy compiler. you can make that value whatever you wish, but when dealing with multiple soy files and something goes wrong, you will be happy for sensible values in there.

there is another interesting method for dealing with soyfiles you might have missed:
SoyFileSet.Builder  addVolatile(File inputFile)